# WPF Material Design Update window Context on dialog close?

Tags: c#, wpf, material-design

I am implementing MaterialDesign for my WPF app (https://github.com/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit). I Implement the Snackbar menu exactly the same  and I have a few Dialogs to catch user input.

The context gets set for each window to display in my snackbar correctly on loading BUT when I click on a snack bar item it doesn't update the context. I'm not sure how to do this

Also when the dialog closes (onclosed event) I want to fire an action to update the context for the user to see the latest grid with the latest values.

Here is my ContentItem class

```
public class ContentItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name;
    private object _content;
    private Thickness _marginRequirement = new Thickness(16);

    public ContentItem(string name, object content)
    {
        _name = name;
        Content = content;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get => _name;
        set => this.MutateVerbose(ref _name, value, RaisePropertyChanged());
    }

    public object Content
    {
        get => _content;
        set => this.MutateVerbose(ref _content, value, RaisePropertyChanged());
    }

    public Thickness MarginRequirement
    {
        get => _marginRequirement;
        set => this.MutateVerbose(ref _marginRequirement, value, RaisePropertyChanged());
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private Action<PropertyChangedEventArgs> RaisePropertyChanged()
    {
        return args => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, args);
    }
}
```

Here is my MainWindowViewModel - I add context when the window gets instantiated and this is the context I want to update on a snackbar click or a dialog closed event

```
public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public MainWindowViewModel(ISnackbarMessageQueue snackbarMessageQueue)
    {
        if (snackbarMessageQueue == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(snackbarMessageQueue));

        ContentItems = new[]
        {
            new ContentItem("Sales", new SalesWindow()),
            new ContentItem("Stock Reeived", new StockWindow()),
            new ContentItem("Petty Cash", new PettyCashWindow()),
            new ContentItem("Banked", new BankedWindow())
        };
    }

    public ContentItem[] ContentItems { get; }
}
```

This is how its called when the app is opened (MainWindow)

```
 InitializeComponent();
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2500);
        }).ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            //note you can use the message queue from any thread, but just for the demo here we 
            //need to get the message queue from the snackbar, so need to be on the dispatcher
            MainSnackbar.MessageQueue.Enqueue("Welcome to DirectS");
        }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

        //Set DataContext
        DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel(MainSnackbar.MessageQueue);
```

In short I need to update the context of the windows when a "ContentItem" is clicked and when a Dialog closed event is fired.....How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In material desgin as with the demo, the menu panel is a listbox. Create a method that fires after a dialog closed event or a panel click event "UIElement_OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp" as the example below.

```
<ListBox x:Name="DemoItemsListBox" Margin="0 16 0 16" SelectedIndex="0"                         
                         ItemsSource="{Binding ContentItems}"
                         PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="UIElement_OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp">
```

After this grab the listbox item source as DemoItems (as with the material design example) loop through your array, find the window you want to update by name and instantiate a new window for the content item.

```
private void UIElement_OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        //until we had a StaysOpen glag to Drawer, this will help with scroll bars
        var dependencyObject = Mouse.Captured as DependencyObject;
        while (dependencyObject != null)
        {
            if (dependencyObject is ScrollBar) return;
            dependencyObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dependencyObject);
        }

        MenuToggleButton.IsChecked = false;

        var listBox = sender as ListBox;
        UpdateContentItems.Set(listBox);
    }
```

Here is my static class to help update the window context

```
public static class UpdateContentItems
{
    public static void Set(ListBox listBox)
    {
        var items = listBox.ItemsSource;
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            var contentItem = item as ContentItem;
            if (contentItem.Name == "Banked")
            {
                contentItem.Content = new BankedWindow();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Property changed event is fired and your windows will now be up to date.

It can be cleaned up a bit more but hopefully this helps.